# The style of the web page is breaking in the mobile browser image spills over, header overlaps with column

Tags: html, css

I have this url:

oios.kemne.com

when I visit this in the mobile I get this:

[image]

The relevant html segment is as follows:

```
<div class="focus">

    <div id="f_image">
        <img src="/assets/6112e42e/images/man.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div id="text4">
        <div id="f_heading"></div>
        <div id="f_tex1"></div>
        <div id="f_tex2"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

is the container.

is the image holder.

is the header.

is the column 1.

is the column 2.

The relevant css styles are as follows:

```
#f_image {
    width: 35%;
    height: 111px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}


.focus {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #DCDDDE;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#text4 {
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#f_heading {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #1A6EB4;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#f_tex1 {
    width: 46%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#f_tex2 {
    width: 46%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

As can be seen from the mobile (note3), the styles are completely messed up. The image spill over the containing div and the heading overlap the column1.

If I remove the width attribute from the #f_image, then the image fits inside the containing div (.f_focus). But the problem is that, it affects the rendering in desktop browser. I can probably use two separate stylesheets for desktop and mobile. But then it would require a lot of rewriting and duplication and the styles would be scattered. More importantly, the logic of the layout is very simple - the image is 35% of the containing div. So if the containing div resizes in the mobile or any other screens, then the image should resize automatically. The fact that removing the width fits the image inside the containing div also bears testimony that there are enough room to accommodate the image. For the rest of things, ie the overlapping of the header with the column, I am not quite sure of the reason of it failing.

I am completely clueless. I even tried to debug the mobile version using firefox remote debugger. So please help me with resolving this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't open the link of your website, it asks for a password.

Comment: Please provide information on what you want as a result otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 `@media-queries` over here. I don't know the width at which you'd like the mobile styles to take over the desktop styles but just for an example, I am using `768px` as the width after which the mobile styles will take over the desktop styles.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

     #f_image img {
          width: 100%;
     }

     #f_heading {
          height: auto;
     }

}
```

Please place the above styles at the bottom of your stylesheet and then try viewing the website on your mobile device or try resizing your browser window to less than 768px.